# Have there been known instances in history when a queen consort slept with someone other than her husband, and no one got hurt? How was that possible?

Tags: monarchy

King Henry VIII executed two of his wives for alleged adultery. This was almost certainly true of one of them, Catherine Howard, while the facts concerning the other one, Anne Boleyn, are in dispute.

When King Christian VIII of Denmark married Princess Caroline of Great Britain, as detailed in the movie ["A Royal Affair,"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A_Royal_Affair), the queen's affair with the court doctor (and royal adviser), Struensee led to the man's overthrow and execution.

In a third situation, Isabella, the wife of King Edward II had an affair with [Mortimer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Invasion_of_England_(1326)) that resulted in the overthrow and (probable) murder of the king by his wife and lover.

As a commenter pointed out, a queen's adultery would likely threaten the succession, with potentially serious consequences for the country.

Are there any "well known" cases in history where it was established that queen consort of a king slept with someone other than her husband, and no one was executed, or was known to get into serious trouble as a result? If so, what were the circumstances that prevented bad consequences? Put another way, why might the threat to the succession or to the country not seem to matter, in such cases?

(A "queen consort" is a the wife of a king. Queen Victoria, who allegedly had some affairs after Prince Albert died, is not in this category. Elizabeth I was known as the "Virgin Queen.")

Comment: Presumably these cases are "well known" because of the consequences. Affairs that were carried out in secrecy (and were either never discovered or quietly hushed up) could quite possibly never become public knowledge.

Comment: How would you know? I hear castles have lots of secret passages.

Comment: If the Queen Consort has an affair and she is fertile, then the line of succession is in dispute - the country is hurt. If she is not fertile, then the line of succession is in danger.  Any affair results in danger of civil war.

Comment: @MarkC.Wallace: That's why this is a "non-trivial" question.

Comment: I imagine the kings feelings would be hurt at a minimum.

Comment: @Oldcat: I meant consequences over and above what any husband would feel. But good point.

Comment: I believe I have made the question less "trivial?"

Comment: Not sure why this is on hold.  Trivia?  What????  Thiis is frustrating to constantly see this when I come on this site.

Comment: @steelerfan: Will you join me in voting to reopen? You have the rep.

Comment: @TomAu Definitely!  I didn't think that I had high enough rep over here.

Comment: Seems odd that the accepted answer doesn't fulfill either of the requirements of the question. Khan's wife didn't have an affair and, since Genghis Khan actively lead a raid to get her back, I'd think that those responsible for her kidnap came to some harm.

Comment: @Steve Bird Actually, despite many records of Genghis Khan's cruelty, there's no record on what he did with his wife's kidnappers. Considering that it's stated as a "rescue", it's very likely he just snuck in, took her out on a horse at the dead of night and that's that.

Comment: @setobot5000, I disagree, I find it unlikely that, given the type of tribal warfare, Genghis Khan would "sneak in" to rescue his wife and given his later power that he wouldn't make a grave example of what happens to anyone with the temerity to kidnap a member of his family.

Comment: @Steven Drennon: I have edited the question to make it less trivial and there are four reopen votes. Is it worth re-opening now?

Comment: @SteveBird 2 Things. 1: This is an event that happened before Genghis Khan was anything other than Temujin the Mongol. He didn't have an army. It was said (although not proven conclusively) that this humiliation was what led him to decide he wanted to be a conqueror. 2: His massacres and battles are recorded in detail by historians, but there's no killings mentioned for this one. I would think it would be mentioned if he actually did hand out violent reprisals.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Not exactly an affair, but Borte, Genghis Khan's first wife, was abducted by a rival tribe. Genghis Khan didn't care and took her back. Chagatai on the other hand kept accusing his elder brother Jochi of not being his father's son because of this, but nobody paid much heed to it.

Why... I guess Mongols just didn't care all that much since their leader was decided by election anyway.

Comment: @Steve Bird: This answer cites a case where the king took back his queen consort without penalty to her or the child (even though she had "technically" been with another man), which was what I was looking for. I re-worded the question so it fits this answer. – Tom Au 5 hours ago

Comment: @TomAu, The second part of your question states "...no one was executed, or got into serious trouble as a result". In this case the perpetrators, the [merkits](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Merkit) were wiped out as a distinct group by Genghis Khan and his sons - which strikes me as "serious trouble".

Comment: @SteveBird "After two decades", not to mention even without this event it's not like Genghis Khan would have left them alone. The connection to Borte's abduction is flimsy at best.

Comment: @SteveBird keep in mind, two decades is how long the Mongols took to conquer the entire Jin Dynasty. If Genghis Khan was angry about his wife's abduction like you say, he sure took his sweet time getting his revenge.

Answer (score 9):

[Caroline of Brunswick](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Caroline_of_Brunswick) who was consort to George IV had many affairs (although technically most of them were before she became Queen consort). While her husband ended up hating her, she was popular enough with the people that she suffered only the gossip and disdain of the court.

Comment: Not a bad answer, although "the dignitaries who led the investigation concluded that there was "no foundation" to the rumours."

Comment: @TomAu Given the people involved and the lack of solid evidence (i.e. the word of someone more important than the servants) I suspect that the dignitaries involved took the path of least resistance. However, her later affair with Pergami (described as "to all appearances man and wife") is much less in doubt.

Answer (score 3):

There were rumors of an affair between Marie-Antoinette and Fersen (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marie_Antoinette). The French Wikipedia entry even suggests that Marie-Antoinette had affairs with women (https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marie-Antoinette_d%27Autriche).

There were also rumors of an affair between Cardinal Mazarin and Anne of Austria, some are even suggesting that Louis XIV was the son of Mazarin and not Louis XIII. (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cardinal_Mazarin).

But these are just rumors, though they have been around for more than two centuries.